# New Facebook Pixel Will Not Load

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am not really a developer, so excuse the lack of expertise. I am merely a marketer trying to successfully load the new Facebook pixel on a page to track a registration!

The Facebook pixel helper extension on chrome is giving me a `pixel did not load` error message (`event ID: Page View`). Here is a screenshot:

[Pixel helper error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNneb.jpg)

Let me explain the situation:

My company is creating a Facebook campaign where the goal is to track successful conversions. A conversion being when a prospect goes to our landing page and opts in with their name, email and phone. I use to set this up in FB with a tracking conversion pixel. FB told me, however, that they are phasing out this pixel and are instead using a new Facebook pixel.

In FB Ads manager, I copied the new code for the new pixel. I then went to my landing page software, LeadPages.net, and inserted the code into the head tag section.

I published the leadpage thru LeadPage's WP plug-in to our WordPress site. When a prospect clicks on our facebook ad, they go to the landing page. When they opt in, they are taken to a Thank You page. This is where I inserted the new FB pixel code. Here is a screenshot:

[LeadPagesTrackingCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdTct.jpg)

We cannot track successful conversions. I tried altering the code with an action -- a complete registration. This is the snippet of code that I used on the LeadPages thank you page:

```
fbq('track','CompleteRegistration');
```

According to FB, this is the complete registration scenario that tracks when a registration form (opt-in on a landing page) is completed.

That did not work. Facebook ran out of ideas and is suggesting that I post here.

Can anyone help a code-clueless marketer? :)

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: I just had a look and this seems to be fine now. Have you fixed something since you posted this?

Comment: We played around with the code and we still can't get it to recognize a conversion.